# does t include in explorer search as we do in windows 7

Tags: search

When we are uploading any file we may search for the file in the explorer when using windows 7. So my question is will that too will be available in ubuntu.

Comment: I have problems understanding the question plus you seem to want to include a pix that is not there. What you ask is something a BROWSER does and those are the same across different operating system.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of it, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if a File Manager is available in Ubuntu which includes file searching like Windows Explorer then the answer is **YES**. Ubuntu comes preinstalled with ***Nautilus*** a very popular n powerful file manager.

Comment: To use the search feature in nautilus just start type when the window is focused, and it'll automatically start searching the whole file system

Comment: No. You need to press **ctrl + f** or click the search icon to start searching recursively.

Comment: I've just tried it on my nautilus. Just started typing and it searched recursively

Comment: It needs to be turned on manually. By default in new version of Ubuntu recursive search is turned off.

Comment: That must be it then

Comment: I also tried it just now. Recursive is off by default.